# os.listdir() gives a list of files not correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting this weird problem. I must take all the list of files inside a folder but the result of `os.listdir()` gives me a list of a length different from the exact number of files inside that folder. I've also printed this list to check if it takes also something else but not.

```
TRAINING_FILES = os.listdir(TRAINING_DATA)  # length = 7269
with open(LOG_DIR + 'output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for p in TRAINING_FILES: f.write(p + '\n')
```

In this log file I have only `.bin` files, so it takes stuff correctly.

Inside the folder, I've taken all the files with `cmd + a` and dragged outside to display the number which is `7268` and I also checked with the terminal using `ls | wc -l` and I have `7268` files.

Is there something that I don't know?

Comment: have you checked that you don't have hidden files (i.e files that start with a dot) this would not be picked up by `ls` so what happens if you run 'ls -a | wc -l`

Comment: Try `ls -d .*` to list hidden files.

Comment: `ls -a | wc -l` gives me `7271` files because using `ls -d .*` I have also `. .. .DS_Store`

Comment: In the log file I don't have neither `.` nor `..` nor `.DS_Store`

Comment: What about an alternative? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/

Comment: Is for python 3.5 I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Try `ls -1 > ls_files.txt` and then read the lines of `output.txt` and `ls_files.txt`. Pop each in a set and do `output_set - ls_files_set`. This will return the file that `os.listdir()` returns, but that isn't listed by `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a answer to propose to you: Could it be that `ls | wc -l` gives you all the files except `.` `..` and `.DS_Store`. But python `os.listdir(path)` gives you all the files except `.` and `..`. So your missing file is only `.DS_Store`

[`os.listdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

Comment: Yes, I was looking carefully line by line the log file and I find out in the `4365` position `.DS_Store` so that's the problem